# Signals and slots autocomplete in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-studio-addins

I'm trying to set up Visual Studio to develop a Qt application. I'm used to Qt Creator's autocomplete behavior. When the user types `SIGNAL(`, the signals list pops up. Now I'm using VS 2012 with Qt Add-in 1.2.2 for Qt5. And this behavior is missing. Is this expected or can I somehow enable this behavior?

I know about the new connect syntax in Qt5 that allows to pass C++ method reference instead of using Qt macros. But this is not good enough also because the IntelliSense is not smart enough to show only signals and slots while I'm typing connect statement. It shows all class members. So this is also not convenient.

Comment: If you are used to the behavior of Creator then use Creator. VS's autocomplete is very poor without VAX, and even with it, you still won't get the Qt centric behavior. Signals are a Qt think, they are not generic C++, the reason they come out in Creator is it is explicitly implemented. Maybe the Qt addon for VS brings some improvements, but I doubt it makes Qt development as good as it is in Creator. Creator is free and there is no reason not to use it, even if you want to use the MS compiler.

Comment: What the Qt addon gives you is more in the nature of project management.  Example, your create a class, and add the QOBJECT macro.  PRESTO!!  Your project will be updated to automatically run moc on your class and link with the generated files. Without this it would be intolerable to work with VS. But sadly intellisense is not one of those areas that they have added a lot of things. Maybe in the future.

Comment: There is no MSVC profiler integration in QtCreator, so both QtCreator and MSVC have poor integration on Windows.